# How to clean up tk.createcommand?

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl

The following example will create a memory leak because of `tk.createcommand`:

```
import tkinter
import gc

class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.tk = tkinter.Tcl()
        self.tk.createcommand("someCommand", self.someCommand)

    def someCommand(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":

    while 1:
        f = Foo()
        # f.tk.deletecommand("someCommand")
        # del f
        # gc.collect()
```

If you remove `tk.createcommand` everything runs fine, `del f` and `gc.collect()` have no effect, and the `tk.deletecommand` will throw an `_tkinter.TclError: can't delete Tcl command`.

Is there any way to remove the created command or to clean up the memory? I am **not** working with tkinter GUI, I need this to call some legacy tcl code.

```
python                                                                                                                         
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 26 2019, 21:43:19) 
[GCC 8.2.1 20181127] on linux
```

Comment: It isn't the command that's leaking memory, it's the entire Tcl environment you're creating along with each instance of `Foo`.  I'm not aware of any way to dispose of that.

Comment: But if I remove the `createcommand` no memory is leaking (or at least it's leaking very slowly). So is this a bug?

Comment: It most definitely ought to be possible to dispose the Tcl environment, or at least the Tcl interpreter. That's _designed_ to be a disposable context (though Tk is a bit fussier). Doesn't appear to be exposed though.

Comment: @OcasoProtal: Do you need a new `tkinter.Tcl()` instance for every new `Foo()`?

Comment: @stovfl unfortunately yes, due to side side effects in the legacy code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, albeit this solution is not working in my case. Don't know why, but we are doing a little more than this small demo code, so I switched to `multiprocessing`.

You have to explicitly call `deletecommand`:

```
import tkinter
import gc

class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.tk = tkinter.Tcl()
        self.tk.createcommand("someCommand", self.someCommand)
        print("Foo intialized")
        # self.tk.eval('rename someCommand ""')

    def someCommand(self):
        pass

    def __del__(self):
        print("DESTRUCTOR called!")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    while 1:
        f = Foo()
        f.tk.tk.deletecommand("someCommand")
        del f
        gc.collect()
```

Beware! Puting the call in `__del__` will not work, because the destructor will never get called due to the memory leak:

```
import tkinter
import gc

class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.tk = tkinter.Tcl()
        self.tk.createcommand("someCommand", self.someCommand)
        print("Foo intialized")
        # self.tk.eval('rename someCommand ""')

    def someCommand(self):
        pass

    def __del__(self):
        f.tk.tk.deletecommand("someCommand")
        print("DESTRUCTOR called!")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    while 1:
        f = Foo()
        # f.tk.tk.deletecommand("someCommand")
        del f
        gc.collect()
```

Answer (score 2):

While in a full Tcl environment interpreters are entirely destroyable (if not cheap) objects, Tkinter's own reference Tcl interpreter (a fairly heavyweight entity) does not appear to be an easy one to delete; it's coupled to the lifespan of the underlying C `_tkinter` object, and that's a little complex… to the point where it's tricky for me to tell if deleting that and garbage collecting it would result in things becoming reloadable or whether you'd be just setting yourself up for future weirdness. It *probably* works, provided you're not loading Tk too (as Tk is a bit fussier). Eventually.

Because of that, it's *really* best if you can avoid reloading that if you don't need to, and it's also best if you don't make new instances of `Tcl()` if you don't actually need them. It is after all a bit like saying make a new Python interpreter… so it should probably not be done in a tight loop in ordinary code.

You've already found `deletecommand`; commands *are* designed to be cheap to create and destroy.

---

Is it possible to run the code inside a subprocess instead? Without Tk about, that should be fairly simple, and processes are cleaned up extremely well by the OS. There are many ways to do this; which one is best will depend on the details of what you're doing (especially how much interactivity there is and how much data you're moving).